# Spring Security - Request Method 'POST' Not Supported

Tags: spring, spring-security

After upgrading from Spring Security 4 to 5 (which involved just updating the version in POM), authentication is now broken. Spring security version is `5.5.1`. It used to work just fine in Spring Security 4. Below is the spring config.

```
@Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/app*/**", "/resources/**");
  }
```

```
http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

http.formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
        .usernameParameter("j_username").passwordParameter("j_password")
        .permitAll()
        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
        .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());

http.logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID" )
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll();

http.csrf().disable();

http.requestCache().disable();

//Custom filters
```

Spring Security Debug Logs -

```
************************************************************

Request received for POST '/j_spring_security_check':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@fda4338

servletPath:/j_spring_security_check
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 77
cache-control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
origin: http://localhost:8080
.
.
.


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  ConcurrentSessionFilter
  SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  LogbackMappedDiagnosticContextSecurityContextFilter
  RequestLoggingFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************

2021-06-23 21:56:14,908 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

Am not sure what all has changed between the versions which leads to this. The post URL is a spring security URL and there is no extra configuration that is required for it.

Answer (score 0):

The default URL where the Spring Login will POST to trigger the authentication process is `/login`, which used to be `/j_spring_security_check`.

If you gonna use the defaults you can omit these 2 lines

```
.loginProcessingUrl("/login")
.usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
```

note that it is now `username` and `password`